# How to define an array of generic objects in TypeScript, each item having a different template parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to define an array of fields for a form, where each item may have a different type. I've defined these types:

```
  interface FormData{
    value1:number
    value2:number|null
    value3:string
    value4:boolean
  }

  interface Field<T,K extends keyof T,TV=T[K]>{
    key:K&string
    value:TV
    validation?:(value:TV)=>boolean
  }
```

Defining an individual field works fine:

```
  const field:Field<FormData,'value1'>={
    key:'value1',
    value:1,
    validation(value:number):boolean{
      return value<3
    }
  }
```

But when defining an array for several items, like this:

```
  const fields:Field<FormData,keyof FormData>[]=[
    {
      key:'value1',
      value:1,
      validation(value:number):boolean{
        return value<3
      }
    },
    {
      key:'value3',
      value:'xxx',
      validation(value:string):boolean{
        return value!=='xxx'
      }
    }
  ]
```

TypeScript is:

1. Allowing `value` be of any type, as long as it's `number|null|string|undefined` (eg a string for `value1`)
2. Complaining about the `validation()` functions, since they don't accept `number|null|string|undefined` as a parameter

Is there a way to help TS infer the correct type of each item within the array? Ideally, I'd also would like to define the array as `Field<FormData>[]`.

I'm using TypeScript 4.3.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zJjN) work for your use cases?  I'd be much more inclined to make `Field<T>` a union and not generic in `K extends keyof T`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you continue to make your type `Field<T, K>` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the key `K`, then you will indeed find it annoying to represent an array of `Field<T, ??>` for different keys `K`.  There are ways to do it with [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), but really, this would require you to specify or have the compiler infer a particular array of key types.  But you don't care about *which* keys are used, as long as they are all *some* actual keys.

This is a canonical use case for [existentially quantified generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), which are not directly supported in TypeScript.  (There is a request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), but for now this is a missing feature.)  TypeScript's generics, like most languages' generics, are *universally quantified*, which you can think of as being an infinite [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of types.  Existentially quantified generics, on the other hand, act as infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of types.

But wait, your `FormData` interface, like most object types, has a *finite* list of keys.  You don't need an infinite union; you can just use a union!  Meaning, make a union of your original `Field<FormData, K>` type, for each `K` in `keyof FormData`. Here's one way to define it:

```
  type Field<T> = { [K in Extract<keyof T, string>]-?: {
    key: K
    value: T[K],
    validation?: (value: T[K]) => boolean
  } }[Extract<keyof T, string>];
```

This builds a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with the field type you want for each key `K` in `keyof T`, and then immediately [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that mapped type to get a union of its properties.

You can see that it makes the type you need:

```
  type FieldFormData = Field<FormData>;

  /* type FieldFormData = {
    key: "value1";
    value: number;
    validation?: ((value: number) => boolean) | undefined;
} | {
    key: "value2";
    value: number | null;
    validation?: ((value: number | null) => boolean) | undefined;
} | {
    key: "value3";
    value: string;
    validation?: ((value: string) => boolean) | undefined;
} | {
    ...;
} */
```

And now that there is no explicit `K` mentioned in the type, you can just use `Array<Field<FormData>>`:

```
const fields: Field<FormData>[] = [
  {
    key: 'value1',
    value: 1,
    validation(value: number): boolean {
      return value < 3
    }
  },
  {
    key: 'value3',
    value: 'xxx',
    validation(value: string): boolean {
      return value !== 'xxx'
    }
  }
]
```

and it will also catch errors:

```
const badFields: Field<FormData>[] = [
  { key: "value2", value: "oops" }, // error!
  { key: "value4", value: true } // okay
]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgGIAiehxxAlsAC4QBOAZhUpQPbsw1ECxB0GDAG6YArhACMALhIywAIw5EJSaRjkAmZcFUb2SAD4qMGLRN1yAzMqgt2zAOa2psiABZlanx8GBAgwF4AvvQMLACeMFSMEBgAJgA8ACoAfEgAvHhIANoA0kjMSACiAB6uCCxpANYQsXycSBkANEgubsDuWQC6ALQA-MoE2khNscrFXsT2EMoZJQMd8zqYjCkijHzAY0gAFIvLqwCUeTmBwaHhEhFIEYXVtfD1063tXT0eg9HEOIJXhJVL8QTCUR5EHJdLgoQiEBZAFIAD0ACokEDErD4ZCxPkJtppsoAESLeSkgDcG1OKnUHBpk10212+0ORxOPiMJg4l1y1yCITCl0sMmAKQgnGYEBSTKeFnExOaZMW+mptO59NMiuM1nldi2OxYewOyk5dOMDLMlj1GH5gtuIsV4sl0uAsvlj0sRIkJKQ5J8Dg1zK1vz6Bu8GFZJvZ5q5eiW3VcHgdSBuwuAoqQrqlMrlWm9SokADoy16kOjUSj4PsXEhpbDlJRQXCBAjRDlCRt-QByCm99ahxPKeRD7Qs42mhNyHnW84BIV3YvadgQFgydjATaJpBpJAODZRB41ussButqDN1tpPGIrKFAbQwobX3KmZIfs+eSDjYLLVjn+O4xtOlq8uwC7pkuYQrpMa4bluO5yHuB5Ace2gROOEhvn6KqfosDi-pM-4jp+VTkURxGTmywAzkm4buJBGbLjhq7rpu26LEgACEuT5L25FVL2aFHl4AynsA9ZqCAKQtrCV4wqkt7tviD5PvkL6TLgUx4YGibql0dKkkEMBQKSTxdKiqJIBw7ACNxr46R+elyL4pKGVqrjIY8VlIHwDQgLEYnRFE+AREAA)