# How to declare a Map<T, K> which T should be a variadic class and K should be an instance of T?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to declare a `Map<T, K>` type and the keys in the map is classes and values of the map should be instances of the corresponding key. For example:

```
class X {}

type InstanceMap = // the type that I want to declare

const map: InstanceMap = new Map();
map.set( X, new X() );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, it would require [existentially quantified generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68304361/1048572). You can do

```
type InstanceMap<T> = Map<{new (): T}, T>
```

using a [constructor type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36886082/1048572) for the key, but this would only allow you to store a specific class (and maybe subclasses?) but not *any* class. Your code would compile with `const map: InstanceMap<X> = new Map();`, but `map.set(Y, new Y())` would fail.

Instead of trying to instantiate a `Map` type, we could try to come up with our own interface where the existential quantifier is delegated to the individual methods:

```
interface InstanceMap {
    set<T>(c: new () => T, i: T): void;
    get<T>(c: new () => T): T | undefined;
}
```

This works for `set` and `get`, but breaks down as soon as you try to declare `forEach` or iterators.