# Type for array, where each generic element is a separate key-type pair, then loop on that array

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

Let's say I have the following enum and type declared in my code:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
};

type MyType = {
    firstKey: string | null,
    secondKey: boolean,
    thirdKey: MyEnum
}
```

Then, using the type, I declare a variable that looks like this

```js
let globalObject: MyType = {
    firstKey: "String",
    secondKey: false,
    thirdKey: MyEnum.FIRST
}
```

Based on [the answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68352232), I have created the following generic type:

```js
type MainFormDataField<T extends MyType> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    sKey: K;
    vValue: T[K];
  };
}[keyof T];
```

I want to use it in a function that assigns a value to the specific key of the previously created object. I don't want to modify the object directly. The reason for this is that I need to execute some logic before and after each change of any value in the object.
When I pass an array of objects into the function, everything works as expected. I have an array with multiple objects and type of value of each object is specific for the selected key - it does not combine type of all values in the array. However, in the function itself it does not work this way. The type of the value property is a union of all possible types for each key.

```js
function setSomeValue(elements?: MyFieldType<MyType>[]) {
    if(!elements) {
        // Some alternative logic
        return;
    }

    // Some logic required before the value changes

    for (const element of elements) {
        globalObject[element.key] = element.value; // Type 'string | boolean | MyEnum | null' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    }

    // Some logic required after the value changes
}

setSomeValue([{key: "secondKey", value: false}, {key:"thirdKey", value: false}]) // Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.
```

How can I solve this?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKCpqAxAkgJQGUAVAGgy0IQGEB5AOQBE0BfAbjTQBc4AHYWHGJ8BAXijosUAGYBLAE4BnLgGlgcAFxRl82SADmUAD5RwAGzPkpi4AGMA9iAAmazVABG9%202eABDEFZYXAAWCi7qWvBIkKycPPyC2LLAZk7C-AA8xFDAAB5coE6KgunAAHxQ4pJQANoqUHpQANbq9tJQxAC6WtWYLW4qHFIAbr5mYMBaxHWdQ1DsrDX9bR2znD5cUPpm9u5jtO4AVnZckUIilRIUmHJKqhFQAESEXLoGj4GYNg7OrlrSYxsnygITCf0E0QgADo8ERiLE0NIwCBbFxZI5tMAuIR7BBgAA1MYTAAUKWAeJAXEUAH4zkkUmkRBl4KUyjVOgBKK5SWTSYkAQjJFKpXN6UigAHoJVAcXioGMCvIQL40cMBDt9LJbNdxfIsWAlXNMCxOFIpTLcer7JrbFA9QBHMAKYBODzAaT2PUg4ICUbjAS2YL%20fTARSmrAe%20RQYk-ZQ5HzCqArIWgEXc8WYba7fZHE41FOUqH9TqXAtcKF%20iZsSXS0pQADkOj0hhMnm8fhAxghyC75jM9YaxRA9k2vkUilk%20mV7h8IPsIIu9ZAwDV8nrUI6i77A9kQ5H8vHk%20ns648-iAiXK%20Aa6hOpNOvNsqtNrtwEdztdvmkiu9vqJAaDAxQwRGxsUtQl-WJGoUH6LRHm%20RxwjgD4oErSYZEBYAWFICRYMeUF5CQlC0P%20TCWE5GtNwSesATMGwdz3UdDynXwZwEU8F2oqJkHXIA)

Comment: There is a hack like in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXgq8W). Would it work?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes, this is what I meant! The `setSomeValue` function does not accept a boolean value for `key: 'thirdKey'` (but only `MyEnum`) as intended. However, it does not produce an error on assignment.

Comment: where do you want to have the assignment error?

Comment: What I meant is that it does not produce an error on assignment unlike in the code provided by me, which is a good thing in this case :) Thank you for your assistance. Please provide your response as an answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: Here you go with another solution. Let me know which one you prefer so I can put it in the answer.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOXAyN)

Comment: The second option is even better. It maintains type safety even when used outside of the `setSomeValue` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is a suggested refactor described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47109), which considers moving to generics. We will need to add another function responsible for setting a single field. This function will accept generic parameters constrained to be a key of `MyType`  and by using the type mentioned below we will accept the `element` argument:

```
type SetArgs<T extends keyof MyType> = {
  [K in T]: {
    key: K;
    value: MyType[K];
  };
}[T];

const set = <T extends keyof MyType>(obj: MyType, element: SetArgs<T>) => {
  obj[element.key] = element.value;
};
```

By using the generics we prevent the compiler from narrowing the type. For example, in the `set` function the `element.key` is no longer showing exact values of it in union, but rather generic version, which is what we are looking for.

Usage:

```
function setSomeValue<T extends MyFieldType<MyType>>(elements?: T[]) {
  if (!elements) {
    return;
  }


  for (const element of elements) {
    set(globalObject, element); // no error
  }
}
```

Looks good!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAYgSQEoDKAKgDQZQEIDCA8gHIAiZAvmmgC5wAOwscR3XgF4o6TADMAlgCcAzuwDSwOAC4o86ZJABzKAB8o4ADZGA3OVnAAxgHsQAEyWqoAIxs2jwAIYhzmdgAWMo7KavBIkObM5hyCfFiSwEb2AjwAPERQwAAe7KD2snypwAB8UCJiUADaClBaUADWyjbiUEQAumqVmE3OCn6YUABuXkZgwGpENe0D0WjMVb0tbTNsnuxQ2kY2LqM0LgBW1uxh-HEV5FJyiqFQAOQE7Jo6d2SYlrYOTmrio5ZvUECwW+fAiEAAdLhCKR5jFODwKMB2ABBaTaWQZLK5fKFJateDFMoXTA1OogFZdcg9W79KnDUbjU7FaazKJVDoxT7ydRI8pQTE5PIOXHNfFnHglAAUOwOTMEJCynggoBOiJRaIxRBKAEpymVKjKqklgMqQOxwb12nzjabzSMxsAojFxGAQFZ2JI7Dz2AQbMqAGoM4AC7HC+KJZLFNIEwQlKU2lWyAD8kyq7V1lUkrUlAEIE2bZBm6QB6YsUP28UZ5aQgLweoa8bbaSRWOnSJFgGuzNiYUvl5VQJstqDtgCOYBkwHsrmA4hs7cBAV49vGUCsAR82mAsh7UDn0igkq5G3zG2Wp8LojplnYkq2Oz2h2OCtP2u75D7voHQ6sI+A48nacvHEatF2XIM1w3HRt3mNgby-YBAwdSUqnIFBGluO4PjsEI4FeekHR+P5eGYAF0N6NQ7iBaRcPwlcJj3YioFItB01MKA+2Ke5fiMSw7jqQoQBsDYvFkWRJG0WsXE8QEbEBOI7nCZA7nBNAgA)